# Reading 2D array from file

Tags: python, list, file, file-writing, file-read

Im working on a simulation project in Python and encountered a problem. I need to save a 2D array to a file, so I can use data from it later. The initial list looks like this:

```
int_array3 = [[14,5], [9,3], [25,5]]
#writing to file:
with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
for num in int_array3:
    f.write("%s\n" % num)
```

The data in file looks like this:

```
[14  5]
[9 3]
[25  6]
```

I have tired this piece of code to read it, but it is not an integer list.

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
result = f.readlines()
result = [x.strip() for x in result]
```

The result list looks like this:

```
['[14  5]', '[9 3]', '[25  6]']
```

Can someone recommend me how to make it work? I want the result list to be shaped the same way my initial list was. I am using numpy.

Comment: **I am using numpy** so `int_array3` is an `np.array`?

Comment: **I have tired this piece of code to read it** which one? You only show how you write the file.

Comment: @Countour-Integral My bad, I edited it so it is included.

Answer (score 0):

How about writing only numbers without `[]` to file? You can achieve that with nested `for` loop during writing to file. Just remember to separate numbers (with space for example).
Then, you could read your file line by line, use `split()`, and then you'll have an array of numbers, but for now it's an array of strings. To make numbers out of it, you'd need to cast string numbers to int. I think the easiest way would be using list comprehension to build new list of numbers.

To illustrate the above, your writing code would be like this:

```
int_array3 = [[14,5], [9,3], [25,5]]
#writing to file:
with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
for vec in int_array3:
    for number in vec:
        f.write("%d " % number)
    f.write("\n")
```

And you could read your wile with:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
for line in f:
    vector = [int(x) for x in line.split()]
    #Do something with vector variable
```

Comment: It seems that   f.write("%d " % num)   is not working, it says: %d format: a number is required, not list

Comment: Yeah, stupid spelling mistake. I meant `f.write("%d " % n)`. The point is to use nested for loop to get access to particular numbers in nested lists. I'll edit my reply right away.

Comment: I edited code example in my answer to be a little bit more readable.

Comment: I tired it and its saves to file as:
14 5 
9 3 
25 5 (as it should)
but when i try to print vector it only shows: [25,5]

Comment: If you used literally the code I posted above, and you didn't do something with `vector` variable in the for loop (ie push it to another list), then it looks like you only use the `vector` variable from the last for loop iteration. You need to do something with `vector` variable each loop iteration, otherwise you will lost the data from all but last iteration.

Comment: I think i got it. I initiated the list, then instead of vector = [int(x).... I did: vector.append([int(x)..... And it looks like everything works fine now. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **eval()** to convert the string to an array like so:

```
A = ['[14  5]', '[9 3]', '[25  6]']
arr = []

for i in range(len(A)):
    l = eval(A[i].split()[0] + ',' + A[i].split()[1])
    arr.append(l)

print(A)
# [[14, 5], [9, 3], [25, 6]]
```

*Feel free to ask for clarifications*

Comment: Do I need to include anything to make it work?  Im getting an error:

  Message=list indices must be integers or slices, not str
   line 54, in <module>
    l = eval(result[i].split()[0] + ',' + result[i].split()[1])

Comment: can you update ur Question with the entire code.